# Custom Wordpress Table wpdb

Tags: database, query, mysql, wpdb

running into issues querying a custom table and getting results.

As of Wordpress 3.9, I can no longer run mysql_query(), and have to use $wpdb->query();

So keeping that in mind:

Old Code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['msg'])) {

global $wpdb;
$vuser_id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_quiz WHERE quiz_id='$vuser_id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$total = $result['total_count'];
```

Updating it what I think would be proper:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['msg'])) {

    global $wpdb;
    $vuser_id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_quiz WHERE quiz_id='$vuser_id'";
    $query = $wpdb->query($sql);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    $total = $result['total_count'];
```

and var_dumping $result gives me `NULL`

and I'm now getting the error:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in  on line 16`

I've tried using `$wpbd->get_row($sql);` `$wpdb->get_results($sql);` all come back null.

If I `exit( $sql );` I can see that the query is being ran correctly
`SELECT * FROM wp_quiz WHERE quiz_id='5925'` and if I run this directly into phpmyadmin, it gives me the correct results.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the `mysql_` functions in WordPress, use `$wpdb`, or in general, as the mysql extension is deprecated, use PDO or Mysqli instead if `wpdb` isn't available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['msg'])) {

    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_quiz WHERE quiz_id='%d'", $user_id);
    $result = $wpdb->get_row($sql, ARRAY_A);
    var_dump($user_id);
    var_dump($result);

    $total = $result['total_count'];
```

Ended up figuring it out after I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you *should not* be handing an untrusted input (in this case, `$_GET['id']` to your database. **Always SQL-escape the query and validate/sanitize the data**. (In the code snippet below, it's SQL-escaped using [`$wpdb->prepare()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) for escaping and `int` typecasting to sanitize to integer value).

Secondly, the `$wpdb` object provides more than just the `query()` function. In your case, it sounds like you're trying to get a set of rows, so you can use the [`get_results()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) function:

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['msg'] ) ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $vuser_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( 
                   $wpdb->prepare( 
                       "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}quiz WHERE quiz_id=%d", 
                       $vuser_id 
                    ) 
    );

    var_dump( $result );

}
```

The `var_dump()` is in there so you can examine exactly what `$wpdb->get_results()` returned. By default it'll be an array of `objects`.

### Reference

- [`wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) on the WordPress Codex

Comment: I was writing almost the same answer but you was faster. I want to make a correction. The prepare method doesn't sanitize the data; this method **scapes** the query string against sql-injection attacks. Sanitize the data is a different thing, for exmpale, typecasting `$_GET['id']` to integer value.

Comment: I'd also add that you shouldn't hardcode the `wp_` prefix, not all sites use `wp_` and it breaks multisite support. Use `$wpdb->prefix` instead. Also @cybmeta it's not a race to answer first, it's a race to answer best =]

Comment: Thank you.  I had forgot to make sure it was an integer, rookie mistake.  I ended up using $wpdb->get_row as an array instead of using $wpdb->get_results.